# Unable to get particular db value using $project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get the title after using aggregation and project but it doesn't show it in my results for some reason. I had asked another question on how to sort an array of documents and it seems I have to use aggregation in order to do what I thought would be a trivial exercise. I was wrong! Anyway... I have commented the code to explain what I am trying to do.

```
Product.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      // get the passed in ID which is a string and needs to be converted to ObjectId format (is there a better way to do this?)
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId)
    }
  },
  {
    // deconstruct the array of objects
    $unwind: "$requests"
  },
  {
    // sort in required order of display
    $sort: {
      "requests.requestDt": -1
    }
  },
  {
    // group by the product ID and push into new array
    $group: {
      "_id": productId,
      "requests": {
        $push: "$requests"
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // project the data I want to display in my view
    $project: {
      "_id": 1,
      "title": 1,
      "requests": 1,
    }
  }
])
```

When I console log this, I get a an output like this:

```
[{
    "_id": "5c4aaa22d0f10e038999afca",
    "requests": [{
            "_id": "5c4b2925d47f6e0a79378010",
            "userId": "5c25cddc73d10c02a75b3d55",
            "firstName": "test",
            "requestDt": "2019-01-25T15:20:05.410Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c4b28e8d47f6e0a7937800f",
            "userId": "5c375260a6f58308e510711a",
            "firstName": "Joe",
            "requestDt": "2019-01-25T15:19:04.258Z"
        }
    ]
}]
```

So, I a getting the product ID from _id in project, as well as the requests, but no title and I don't know why?

Here is the Schema:

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    images: [
        {
            name: {
                type: String
            }
        }
    ],
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    requests: [
        {
             userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
             firstName: {type: String},
             requestDt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
        }
    ]
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I removed $group and I can now access it. My data now looks like:

```
[{
        "_id": "5c4aaa22d0f10e038999afca",
        "title": "Some product",
        "requests": {
            "_id": "5c4b2925d47f6e0a79378010",
            "userId": "5c25cddc73d10c02a75b3d55",
            "firstName": "test",
            "requestDt": "2019-01-25T15:20:05.410Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c4aaa22d0f10e038999afca",
        "title": "Some product",
        "requests": {
            "_id": "5c4b28e8d47f6e0a7937800f",
            "userId": "5c375260a6f58308e510711a",
            "firstName": "Joe",
            "requestDt": "2019-01-25T15:19:04.258Z"
        }
    }
]
```

So now all the data is wrapped in an array and not the requests as well. But I now have duplicate data ie: the product title shows twice but I only need it once.

To access the title I use `product[0].title` and for the requests I put them in a for loop ie: for `(userRequest of product )` and access the data like: `serRequest.requests.motivation`

This seems like a crazy long way around just to sort by 'requests' so if someone has better solution, please post it.

Comment: can you also add the doc from where you trying to fetch?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty, do you mean the schema?

Comment: yeah, schema and a sample doc if possible

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty, I have added the schema to my original question. Not sure what you mean by sample doc?

Comment: If you need title, you would include that field in the `$group` and `$project`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) aggregation to get the `title` value in [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage

```
Product.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId) }},
  { "$unwind": "$requests" },
  { "$sort": { "requests.requestDt": -1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "requests": { "$push": "$requests" },
    "title": { "$first": "$title" }
  }},
  { "$project": { "_id": 1, "title": 1, "requests": 1 }}
])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. How do I loop through this now as `<% for (const userRequest of product) { %>` only gives me one record instead of all of them?

Comment: I think this should be asked as a new question.

Comment: Never mind, I just figured it out. I put the requests into their own 'container' and passed that to the view separately. `requests: product[0].requests,`